# Why are projective spaces over a ring of different dimensions non-isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Let $A$ be a nonzero commutative ring with unit. Define $\mathbb P_A^n$ to be the scheme $\operatorname {Proj} A[T_0,\dots,T_n]$, where the grading on the polynomial ring is by degree. Why is it true that $\mathbb P_A^n\not\cong \mathbb P_A^m$ when $n\neq m$? (I admit I am just guessing here. It seems like it should be true. But I do not know why.)

I am still learning the basics of scheme theory and would prefer as simple an answer as possible. Can this be proved directly from the definitions, without much machinery?

My motivation for asking this question is to show that the only $n$ for which $\mathbb P_A^n$ is affine is $n=0$. I can show that for any $\mathbb P_A^n$, the sheaf of global sections is $A$. So it is easy to see that if $\mathbb P_A^n$ is affine, the only possibility is that it is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} A$. One can directly verify that they are isomorphic for $n=0$, but I do not know how to rule out larger $n$. Hence this question.

Comment: I didn't notice when I wrote my answer (prior to your last edit explaining your motivation): you are not assuming $A$ to be Noetherian? I have to admit that I am terrified of non-Noetherian commutative rings. So I always assume everyone means to write "Noetherian" before "commutative ring", even if they are less than perfect and sometimes forget.

Comment: @Steve There is no Noetherian hypothesis.

Comment: Now you're just trying to frighten me away. It worked! Later, skater.

Comment: @Steve L8ter.  $\textbf{}$

Comment: But, for your motivation, the argument I gave in my comment seems to work just fine: as you write, if projective space over $A$ is affine, then it is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ as a scheme over $A$. I am a coward, but also opportunistic: I will attack non-Noetherian rings if they show weakness.

Comment: @Steve: If $\mathbb{P}^n_A \cong \mathbb{P}^m_A$, then $\mathbb{P}^n_B \cong \mathbb{P}^m_B$ for some finitely generated subring $B$ of $A$, which is hence noetherian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a certain sense in which the dimension tells them apart. This can be made precise by a cohomological argument: Thm. 5.1 of Chapter 3 of Hartshorne implies that there is a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$ with a non-zero cohomology group in dimension $n$. Meanwhile, if $m<n$, then $\mathbb{P}^m$ has a covering by $m+1$ affine schemes, all of whose intersections are also affine, and this implies that no coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^m$ has cohomology in any dimension bigger than $m$ (start with Thm 4.5 of Hartshorne).

Comment: (If you had asked if they were isomorphic *as schemes over $A$*, there would have been an easier answer: reduce to the case of a field by using compatibility of Proj and base change, and then observe that trdeg of function fields tells them apart).

Comment: I like the argument in your comment! It's not quite what I need, but I will certainly remember it for later.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of how to do this problem with my cohomologies tied behind my back.

Comment: After you reduce to the case of fields, you can also compute the dimension of the Zariski tangent space at any point.